# Is it possible to use the Castellar font in Latex?

Tags: fonts

I want to use the Castellar font found in Word in a Latex document. Is there a way to use it in a Latex document even if it is only in the title? Here is an example of what I want.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, yes, if you have this font, then you can use it

Comment: In LuaLatex, `\usepackage{fontspec}` followed by `\newfontfamily\castellar{Castellar}[Scale=MatchUppercase]` should create a `\castellar` command. Does that work?

Answer (score 12):

You can run all codes below by `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

## Main Font

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Castellar}
% \setmainfont{CASTELAR.TTF}
\begin{document}
Test123
\end{document}
```

[image]

## New Font Family

Thanks to @Davislor for his tips on `\DeclareTextFontCommand`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\castellar{Castellar}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
% \newfontfamily\castellar{CASTELAR.TTF}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcastellar}{\castellar}
\begin{document}
Test123 {\castellar Test123} Test123\par
Test123 \textcastellar{Test123} Test123
\end{document}
```

[image]

`Scale=MatchUppercase` is to scale the font being selected to match the current default roman font to the height of the uppercase letters.

## All Character in Castellar

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicodefonttable}
\begin{document}
\displayfonttable{Castellar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

We can see there are no lowercase letters in Castellar font.

Comment: You might also want `\DeclareTextFontCommand\textcastellar{\castellar}`, allowing `\textcastellar{123}` as well as `{\castellar 123}`.

Comment: @Davislor Thank you. I add it to answer.